# Analyse performance / profile Android System? Why is the system slow?

Tags: performance

My Android 4.2.1 tablet is slow, it wasn’t when purchased. As the reason is often the software, I was looking for a tool to analyse the performance *of the whole system*, but couldn’t find any.

What I tried:

- CPU usage monitoring: Only current or accumulated CPU usage
- An app that alerts when any app uses more CPU than a specified threshold: This only alerted quite seldomly, so there doesn’t seem to be an app that uses so much CPU itself

To find out the reason of the slowness, I would like to get an overall view of the system’s performance, showing how much time was spent with which activity. This may include CPU usage, but may also include I/O performance or how long processed waited for I/O etc. For example, Firefox offers a [profiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler).

Or is this not really possible because of Android’s design?
Are there other utilities that might help?

Another point is that Android doesn’t support TRIM until 4.3. Could the usage of nearly two years with many installations and some system resets have caused the flash memory to get so slow that the poor I/O performance now slows down the whole device?

To the manufacturer’s support, I wrote the following problem description:

> Opening of apps takes longer, sometimes everything stands still for
>   some seconds. After the last firmware/Android upgrade (a year ago) I
>   even reinstalled the system. However, after some time, it got slow
>   again.

Only after this vague and undetailed description, the reply said **that the reason would most probably be a hardware defect** and that I should send the device in to be repaired.

How should I continue my analysis? Is the support’s assessment reasonable?

### Update

Recently, a new app was added to the PlayStore concerning exactly one of my desired analysis:

- [CPU Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigbro.ProcessProfiler) (non-free, restricted demo)

Comment: For first-aid and getting started, please consult our [performance tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/performance/info), which has the required pointers. Then come back here and either answer your own question (if you were already able to solve the issue), or [edit] it to include what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks!

Comment: If the manufacturer thinks you should send it in for repair, you should probably do that.